# Only show categories where a course is inside of it

Tags: laravel

Currently my dropdown is show all the categories with this

```
$categories = \App\Category::select('id', 'name', 'parent_id')->get();
```

The requirement has since changed and I now need to change it so only categories with courses attached show.

**Course.php**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
}
```

It's joined together with a Pivot table.

I'm still pretty new to Laravel, could anyone help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$categories = \App\Category::has('courses')->get();
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much!